# What's so significant (special) about the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

I'm interested in both cultural and technical canon. What made it stand out from other starships? Was there only one made? Why does it seem to instill awe in both friend and foe?

Comment: I'm not aware of any evidence in canon - discounting Han's own ego - to suggest that there was *anything* particularly significant about it.

Comment: I'd advise reading the Star Wars Wiki page. It has a lot of information. Apparently the thing has quote the history. It was 63 years old as of Hoth!

Comment: He's made a lot a special modifications.

Comment: Your YouTube link is dead.

Comment: Millenium Falcon definitely was special - Han made so many modifications it's absurd. Engines, hyperdrive, shields, additional weapons, shielded cargo racks, etc etc etc. There was no other YT-1300 that was modified this much

Comment: to address the awe shown by the rebel grunt in the video, that scene takes place on Hoth. By that time, it was probably known the important role that the ship had in the destruction of the Death Star.

Answer (score 4):

A little Googling tells me that the Millennium Falcon is "a modified YT-1300 light freighter" (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon). So I guess many of that model were made, but only one of them was called "Millennium Falcon"

With Han Solo as pilot, it was an infamous smuggling craft. Hans big claim to fame being that he "made the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs" in her (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kessel_Run).
I think this establishes that it was fast and maneuverable, and the Han was will to take risks in her.

Not sure why this would instill awe in foes. It does have gun turrets and shields, but it's not a fighting vessel. Just really good at running away.

Comment: Technically, all Han's claim means is that he doesn't have a clue what a parsec is.

Comment: @user14111 Presumably, if I had to make a guess, everything in the *Star Wars* world has been translated to use terminology that makes sense to us... much like other historical books have been translated into modern English from ancient Greek and Latin among other languages.

Comment: I've often wondered if that parsec line in the original movie is something the script writers later regretted and have had to retcon. I think the official explanation now is that the Millennium Falcon is so maneuverable that it was able to take a straighter line through the Kessel Run, thus shortening the distance.

Comment: @Catija In one of the Han Solo Triology from A.C. Crisoin the explanation was that the Kessel run leads through a series of black holes, called 'the pit'. To make the run shorter than the usual 18 Parsecs, you have to be very fast to plot a course through the different gravity wells. Hence the reference to the smaller distance.There is further Information in the Wookipedia.

Comment: Correction: the Kessel run leads along a Black hole cluster, not through.

Comment: What's really funny is that Han Solo have ever heard of a falcon. https://xkcd.com/890/

Comment: @SredniVashtar: I like xkcd, but that one never made sense to me. :-)  If Star Wars can have humans there's no reason it can't have falcons, or at least a sufficiently close facsimile thereof.